# Sails JS - Display flash message doesn't work on Heroku(production) but works fine in development

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, sails.js

The flash message only works on my local machine during development...It doesn't work when I deployed the app on Heroku. I've been trying to find the answer but couldn't find anything that solves my problem.

api/policies/flash.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.flash = {};
    if(!req.session.flash) return next();
    res.locals.flash = _.clone(req.session.flash);

    // clear flash
    req.session.flash = {};

    next();
};
```

api/controller/UserController.js (within create action) - When the form is submitted successfully, redirect to the homepage and display thank you message.

```
res.redirect("/");
req.flash('signup-message', '<div class="thankyou-message-wrapper bg-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="thankyou-message">Thank you for submitting the form!<br> Our administer will review your submission and publish soon.</span></div>');
```

view/main/index.ejs - This is how I render the message from the UserController.js

```
<%- req.flash('signup-message') %>
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why the flash message is not showing up when I deployed on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the policy to the routes.js file to enable a policy for the homepage.
For example:

```
 '/': {
      view: 'homepage', policy: 'flash'
 }
```

Then in your UserController, add your message to session.flash:

```
 req.session.flash = {
      message : '<div class="thankyou-message-wrapper bg-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="thankyou-message">Thank you for submitting the form!<br> Our administer will review your submission and publish soon.</span></div>'
 }
```

Finally, display the message in your homepage, first check if a message exists and then display:

```
 <% if(flash && flash.message) { %>
      <%- flash.message %>
 <% } %>
```